# Obtaining Cloth in A Dark Room

Tags: a-dark-room

Quite simply, where is cloth obtained from in A Dark Room, and if there is more than one place, is any of them faster? I have only been able to find that it is obtainable from traps, which seem quite slow at the moment (I have just built the workshop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the wiki, [Cloth](http://adarkroom.wikia.com/wiki/Resources) can be acquired in 3 ways:

1. From traps
2. As a reward from combat with some enemies
3. As loot in various parts of the world

Somebody also mentioned in a comment on the wiki page linked above that with respect to fighting enemies for cloth, you should:

> go into the forest and you kill people that come out of houses

I don't know if any of these methods are faster or slower than others, though i would try fighting the enemies if you're finding that farming traps is inefficient and if you have the equipment and wherewithal to do so.